# Dynamically show/hide group footer in Access 2010 report

Tags: ms-access, vba

Is there any way to hide a group footer based on a piece of information in the group header or detail?  I only want to hide it for some records, not the entire report.

For instance, if I have a report of media types, I want to show a disclaimer "*Melts after prolonged exposure to sunlight" in the footer of any vinyl records, but not in the footer for compact disks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I put an if-then into the `GroupHeader_Format` event like this:

```
If media_type = "vinyl" Then
    GroupFooter.Visible = True
Else
    GroupFooter.Visible = False
End If
```